# Some CMD help needed

Tags: windows-7, command-line, cmd.exe

I want to "read" an entire folder, store all the file names and make a separate .AVS for each file using only cmd.

LE : This seems to work ( thnx grawity ) :

```
@echo off
COLOR 0c
cd > "dir.txt"
set /p mypath=<"dir.txt"
set mpath=@Temp
del "%mypath%\dir.txt"
cls
for %%i in (%mypath%\*.mkv) do call :genavs "%%~i"
goto :eof

:genavs
set movie=%~1
echo B=FFAudioSource("%movie%") >> "%movie%.avs"
echo A=FFVideoSource("%movie%").assumefps(24000,1001) >> "%movie%.avs"
echo AudioDub(A, B) >> "%movie%.avs"
echo ConvertAudioTo16bit() >> "%movie%.avs"
echo ConvertToRGB32() >> "%movie%.avs"
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `for` and subroutines:

```
for %%i in (%mypath%\*.mkv) do call :genavs "%%~i"
goto :eof

:genavs
set movie=%~1
set moviedir=%~dp1
(
    echo loadplugin("%moviedir%\bin\FFMS2.dll")
    echo B=FFAudioSource("%movie%")
    echo A=FFVideoSource("%movie%").assumefps(%myfps%)
    echo AudioDub(A, B)
    echo ConvertAudioTo16bit()
    echo ConvertToRGB32()
) >> "%movie%.avs"
goto :eof
```

Comment: Thnx, will try.

Comment: works but >> "%movie%.avs" does not do the job, no .avs files crated.

Comment: Problem solved, thnx grawity.